# Understanding $r:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow Vect(X)$ is the transpose of $d\mu:TX\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*$

Tags: symplectic-geometry

I'm looking at a paper by S.K. Donaldson http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.imperial.ac.uk%2F~skdona%2Fdonaldson-ams.ps&ei=AzoyU9zXKKWC2wWuoIDQDQ&usg=AFQjCNFimn32IRVXGI8YY7IKdR6sd3rwVg&bvm=bv.63738703,d.b2I and here is my second question.

A Lie group acts on a symplectic manifold $(X,\omega)$. Then the derivative of the action is a map 
$$
r:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow Vect(X), 
$$
and a moment map for the action is a map 
$$
\mu:X\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*, 
$$
whose derivative 
$$
d\mu:TX\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^* 
$$
is the transpose of $r$. 
What does Donaldson mean by transpose and why transpose?

Comment: How is the dual of a Lie algebra a Lie algebra itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Lie bracket for $g^*$"? In general the dual of a Lie algebra does not itself carry a natural Lie algebra structure apart from the zero bracket.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I removed question 1 since I misread some online lecture notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $T: V \longrightarrow W$ is a linear map, then the **transpose** of $T$ is the map
$$T^\ast: W^\ast \longrightarrow V^\ast,$$
$$T^\ast(\phi) = \phi \circ T.$$

In our case, the transpose of $r$ is a map
$$r^\ast: \mathrm{Vect}(X)^\ast \longrightarrow \mathfrak{g}^\ast.$$
We have that $\mathrm{Vect}(X)^\ast = \Omega^1(X)$, the space of $1$-forms on $X$. Note that $\mathrm{Vect}(X)$ is the space of sections of $TX$ and $\Omega^1(X)$ is the space of sections of $T^\ast X$. Using the nondegeneracy of the symplectic form, we have a distinguished bundle isomorphism $\varphi: TX \xrightarrow{~\cong~} T^\ast X$. This in turn induces an isomorphism $\tilde{\varphi}: \mathrm{Vect}(X) \xrightarrow{~\cong~} \Omega^1(X)$. Hence we have a map
$$r^\ast \circ \tilde{\varphi}^{-1}: \mathrm{Vect}(X) \longrightarrow \mathfrak{g}^\ast.$$
We may think of this as a map
$$r^\ast \circ \tilde{\varphi}^{-1}: TX \longrightarrow \mathfrak{g}^\ast.$$
Then what Donaldson is saying is that this $r^\ast \circ \tilde{\varphi}^{-1}$ is the same as the differential of the moment map, $d\mu$.

If you haven't already, I would recommend reading the part of McDuff and Salamon's *Introduction to Symplectic Topology* on moment maps and Hamiltonian reduction before getting into Donaldson's paper. They set up the relevant background in more detail and even sketch some of Donaldson's results.